# a SSRS 2008 problem:How to off freeze pane

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have a SSRS 2008 Report and whenever exported  to excel by default it's top rows become freeze.I don't want so.how can i?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The renderer will always freeze whatever rows it produced from the Header of your SSRS report. I don't think you can avoid the freezing unless you remove the Header section of your report.

There is, after doing some research, a [Device Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155069.aspx) flag for `SimplePageHeaders`, which

> Indicates whether the page header of the report is rendered to the Excel page header. A value of false indicates that the page header is rendered to the first row of the worksheet. The default value is false.

Maybe you can use that to prevent the report header from showing up in the Excel document at all. There is [another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3048363/ssrs-2005-set-simplepageheaders-on-the-report-instead-of-the-server) that sort of describes how to reconfigure the Excel renderer on the server (or create a custom one) that will omit the header using the `SimplePageHeaders` device information flag for Excel.

Comment: Hi Cory,where i can find that configuration file?

Comment: Please ,tell me is this possible or not.I want to show the header but don't want that it show in a freez mode.

Comment: The location of the configuration file can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156281.aspx