# Issue while exporting SSRS report into excel

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-grouping

i have 2 tables in a report one below the other,Each will have same number of fields .But when i export the report in to excel each report field is taking 2 columns in the excel and some of  them taking only one excel column for one report field,because of which i am unable to apply filter in the excel.Can some one help me how i can make one excel column for one report field?

Answer (score 0):

This most likely is due to the misalignment of your header cells with your table cells. The Excel export tries to have everything formatted the same as in the report so it will sometimes use two columns for the table cells and merge them so it can align the columns to the header columns. This is problematic when it comes to manipulating and sorting the spreadsheet.

The best way to avoid this is to create an Excel renderer that doesn't render the header part of the report [as described in my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3048363/ssrs-2005-set-simplepageheaders-on-the-report-instead-of-the-server/3058576#3058576).

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be setting the column widths and any present header/footer object widths exactly aligned manually from the properties pane. If you align them using the interface auto align lines there might be slight differences in length which may cause this issue.

By playing with the exported excel column widths, it is possible to spot which column or header/footer object is causing merged cells. So that you can only fix that specific width to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could setup a page break for the second table so that it appears on another tab in Excel. That should resolve the issue of headers between tables not aligning.