# SSRS how to set a merged column to be split in excel

Tags: excel, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, reportbuilder3.0

I have an issue that I know is solve-able, I just cant find the setting or work out how to do it. I have a report where I have merged two columns. Lets say these are columns a and b. I want that when the report is exported to excel that you can click into column A, and it does not merge with column b. this would allow you to filter etc by the data under column a. The reason column a and b are merged in the first place is that the heading needs to go across two cells due to size.

I know this is do-able as it exists on a report i inherited, just i can't find the setting.

Comment: *heading needs to go across two cells due to size* is not a valid reason to merge.  If the right hand cell is empty, the text will overflow.  If you need to center it, merely check the horizontal alignment setting to "center across selection"

Answer (score 2):

This is usually due to the misalignment of your header cells with your table cells. The Excel export tries to have everything formatted the same as in the report so it will sometimes use two columns for the table cells and merge them so it can align the columns to the header columns. This is problematic when it comes to manipulating, filtering and sorting the spreadsheet.

The best way to avoid this is to create an Excel renderer that doesn't render the header part of the report [as described in my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3048363/ssrs-2005-set-simplepageheaders-on-the-report-instead-of-the-server/3058576#3058576).

However, if the cells need to be merged in your report deliberately then you aren't going to be able to do what you want to do using your current report as Excel will duplicate the formatting, including the merged cells.

Probably the only way to get something like what you are after is to create another report that is formatted the way you would like it to be in Excel. In the header of your original report put a text box (or an image with an Excel icon) with an Action on it to open the new, properly formatted, report in Excel, passing across parameters as appropriate. Now the user just need to click on the Action link in the original report to open the more user-friendly report in Excel.

Comment: I actually have two columns merged in the report on purpose and what them to be split in the excel report,  do you still thing it's a misalignment

Comment: If you can't avoid the cell merging, I've added another idea that may assist.

Comment: Thanks Chris for the feedback.