# Remove header from report exported to excel in Sharepoint mode

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, export-to-excel

When our SSRS reports are exported to Excel, some columns are merged which is a problem for example if you want to sort the entries etc. The reason for this merging behavior is that the header of the report is in the body-part of the excel-file, and the excel-export tries to keep the same look as in the report (which messes up the columns). Because of this, I want to remove the header from the body-part of the excel-sheet.

I have tried to edit in the RSReportServer.config-file and set SimplePageHeaders to true as described for example here:
[Exporting from SSRS to Excel with no headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521719/exporting-from-ssrs-to-excel-with-no-headers)

However, I didn't get this to work, although I didn't get any error messages about my config-file-edits from the Event Viewer (it simply said "The RSReportServer.config file has been modified"). I also tried to redeploy the reports and restart Visual Studio. After a while, I found that it might be because we use Sharepoint to view the reports:

*"The Extensions section appears in the rsreportserver.config file **only for native mode report servers**. Extension information for SharePoint mode report servers is stored in the SharePoint configuration database and is configured per Reporting Services service application."*

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157273.aspx#bkmk_extensionsl
(Under *Extensions (RSReportServer.config file) Native Mode*)

Now, I have tried to find the settings in "Sharepoint 2010 Central Administration" (That was my only idea as to where to start looking) but haven't found anything (I have been a little confused on where to look, so I might have missed it). Any ideas? Do you think I'm on the right track?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Ps: Please note that reshaping the textboxes in the header of the report as suggested in other answers to my original problem is not a practical option. 
Pps: Let me know if you need additional details etc. Thanks again.

Comment: Try this solution [SSRS 2005 Set SimplePageHeaders on the report instead of the server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3048363/ssrs-2005-set-simplepageheaders-on-the-report-instead-of-the-server) - Works for me and I use SharePoint integration mode

Comment: I tried it but it didn't make any difference unfortunately. I realized that in the config file, there is one extension called "Excel" and one called "ExcelOpenXml", and the one called "Excel" has visible set to false. I tried the suggested solution for both of these (one at a time) (removing the "visible='false'" from the "Excel" one) but neither made any difference. Actually, when I set visible to false to some of the other render extensions, it didn't affect the export options either. I might be missing something obvious as I'm pretty new to this. Thanks for the suggestion none the less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We managed to solve the problem by configuring the excel rendering extension in the Sharepoint Configuration Database using Powershell. Since we were in Sharepoint mode in Reporting Services 2012, the rsreportserver.config-files were apparently not read at all. More detailed info can be found here:

http://prologika.com/CS/blogs/blog/archive/2011/11/15/report-server-settings-in-sql-server-2012-sharepoint-integration-mode.aspx

And here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jtarquino/archive/2011/10/25/sql-server-2012-reporting-services-sharepoint-integrated-mode.aspx