# SSRS Export to pipe delimited file loose its headers

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

A team I work with has created a report in SSRS that they export to a .txt file for me to upload into SQL using SSIS.  This issue is that there are no column headers.  I ran the report in report builder and the headers are there until I export to txt.  They are there in excel but we need it as a csv. Has anyone else encountered this and if so how did you resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For XML and CSV there are properties to control export behaviour, if the result is different from what you expected

**DataElementName:** this is the title of the exported column/field. Default is blank
**DataElementOutput:** set if you want the control whether the column will be exported or not. Defaults to auto