# SSRS Excel Output - Hidden cell only in the most right of the table

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I have an SSRS report with I need to export to Excel. My problem is, whatever I've tried, there is an extra column hidden in the right of my table.

[image]

- Tried adding extra blank column, no help.
- Tried removing the headers Page:4, no help.
- There is no blank space on the report design. Added some, did not help.
- No textbox used (when Page:4 removed). No hidden column in the table.
- Worked with POINTs instead of INCHs, no help.
- Changed the location of the table `0.1cm,0`, no help and it caused a hidden column A.

I think I read all the SO posts related to extra merged/hidden columns, none of them helped. Any advice would be so appreciated.

Comment: This will be caused by a misalignment of the header objects with the table objects. The best way to get around this is to strip the headers out, either by [adding a new renderer option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3048363/ssrs-2005-set-simplepageheaders-on-the-report-instead-of-the-server/3058576#3058576) or [doing it manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521719/exporting-from-ssrs-to-excel-with-no-headers/540759#540759)

Comment: As Chris said, this is usually caused by misaligned items. When SSRS renders Excel, it tries to mimic the report layout as closely as possible. If say, a text title was 20cm wide but the table underneath was 19.9cm wide in total, then a 1mm column would be added to that the text box will align to the report design.